# Opengl 3.1 GLSL 140 Outputting White In Fragment Shader in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glm-math

I am stuck using a laptop with no support for OpenGL 3.3 or anything higher than 3.1. This is problematic as I am not entirely familiar with this version so I am learning how to use things again. My problem is that for some reason, my fragment shader is only outputting in white. I'm not quite sure what's wrong, but I get the feeling that it has something to do with the way I set the VBO data as this has recently changed in my code. Right now, I'm trying to convert my old rendering engine (written in OpenGL 3.3) to OpenGL 3.1. This is because of the limitations set by my old laptop. This is why I am using a struct for the `Vertex` which includes `BiTangent` and `Tangent` values.

My Code:

```
struct Vertex {
    // Position
    glm::vec3 Position;
    // Normals
    glm::vec3 Normal;
    // Texture Coordinates
    glm::vec2 TexCoords;
    // BiTangent
    glm::vec3 BiTangent;
    // Tangent
    glm::vec3 Tangent;
};

struct Texture {
    unsigned int id;
    int number;
};

class Mesh {

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    std::vector<Texture> textures;

    unsigned int VAO, VBO[5], EBO;

public:
    Mesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<unsigned int> indices, std::vector<Texture> textures) {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->textures = textures;

        setupMesh();
    };

    void setupMesh() {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(4, VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        int stride = 14;

        // Position
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Normal
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // Texture Coordinates
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)6);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        // BiTangent
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[3]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)8);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

        // Tangent
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[4]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)11);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

        // Element Buffer Object
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Unbind
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    };

    void Draw(ShaderProgram shader) {
        for (int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {

            // Give textures the proper id and bind them
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + textures[i].number);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i].id);
        }

        // Draw
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Unbind
        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

};
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 140 core
in vec3 aPos;
in vec3 aColor;
in vec2 aTexCoords;
in vec3 aBiTangent;
in vec3 aTangent;

out vec3 Color;

void main(void){

    Color = vec3(aColor);

    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 140 core
out vec4 FragColor;

//precision highp float;

in  vec3 Color;

void main(void)
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

I tried manually setting a color to override displaying the normals, but the output is still white.

**EDIT:**

If I can generate one VBO instead of 4, that would be useful. My question for that is how I'm supposed to access the vertex data from the shaders when using one VBO.

Comment: *"[...] My question for that is how I'm supposed to access the vertex data from the shaders when using one VBO."* - There is no difference in the shader code, just the vertex specification is different.

Comment: There is no further obvious issue in this part of the code. If it still doesn't work, then there is another bug somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling glUseProgram with your compiled shader program, to make it active? You call Draw with a ShaderProgram object that we cannot see, so it's hard to know. In my experience white output is usually because no program is bound.

Comment: Hey! I can't remember exactly how I fixed it, but I figured things out quite a while ago. Looking at this, I should probably delete or archive or do whatever to this question since it seems to be very useless. I do remember though that the solution was something fairly obvious and that it was in a different part of the code. I think it might have been from not calling glUseProgram(), but I can't say for sure. Anyway, thanks for putting forth an effort to help :) I will delete this question in 24hrs or so

Comment: So yeah, never mind because I can't delete it

Answer (score 2):

If a named buffer object is bound, then the last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is treated as a **byte offset** into the buffer object's data store.
Hence the offset has to be `sizeof(float)*number` rather than `number`:

For instance:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)3);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    stride * sizeof(float), (void*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
```

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)6);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
    stride * sizeof(float), (void*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
```

...

---

Furthermore, the version specification is invalide. There is no GLSL 1.40 core version. Remove the token `core` in the vertex and in the fragment shader:

<s>`#version 140 core`</s>

```c
#version 140
```

`core` is introduced in [OpenGL Shading Language 1.50](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf).

I recommend to check if the shader compilation succeeded and if the program object linked successfully. See [Shader Compilation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation).
If the compiling of a shader succeeded can be checked by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`. If the linking of a program was successful can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_LINK_STATUS`.